# Long Polling causing server problems?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-polling

I've finally made a simple chat page that I had wanted to make for a while now, but I'm running into problems with my servers.

I'm not sure if long polling is the correct term, but from what I understand, I think it is. I have an ajax call to a php page that checks a mysql database for messages with times newer than the time sent in the ajax request. If there isn't a newer message, it keeps looping and checking until there is. Else, it just returns the new messages and the client script sends another ajax request as soon as it gets the messages.

Everything is working fine, except for the part where the server on 000webhost stops responding after a few chat messages, and the server on x10 hosting gives me a message about hitting a resource limit.

Maybe this is a dumb way to do a chat system, but it's all I know how to do. If there is a better way please let me know.

edit: Holy hell, it's just occurred to me that I didn't put any sleep time in the while loop on the server.

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of cometd: http://cometd.org/

Comment: A link doesn't help at all. I have no idea what cometd is, and the description on their site, "scalable HTTP-based event routing bus", isn't helping at all. I hate trying to use things I know nothing about, I'd rather work my way to up to understanding them before I do. Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of reading on this, but I disbelieve that free web hosting is going to allow to do what you are thinking of doing. PHP was also not really designed to create chat systems.

I would recommend using [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/), and use for example, [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) with [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), or Tornado with Python; There is a lot of solutions out there, but most of them would require you to run your own server since it requires to run a whole program that interacts with many connections at once instead of simple scripts that just start and finish with a single connection.

Comment: What is a websocket though? Sorry for being a noob, but I'm definitely willing to learn.

Comment: I totally agree with using node.js for this sort of thing; it's designed to scale well to lots of concurrent connections in a way that more traditional web servers don't handle well. I'm not so sure about websockets though; I'd prefer the extra HTTP overhead of long-polling over the [browser support limitations](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets) enforced by relying on websockets.

Comment: I have no idea what nodejs is though. I don't know how it works or how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the same strategy whether there are newer messages on the server or not. The server would always return a list of newer messages - this list could be empty when there are no newer messages. The empty list could be also be encoded as a special data token.
The client then proceeds in both cases the same way: it processes the received data and requests new messages after a time period.

Comment: If I use timeouts to check the server, then it's no longer instant. If I return without a new message, then it will continue sending and receiving requests as fast as possible, which would bog down the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you sleep(1) your code on each loop, the code gonna enter the loop several times per second, stressing your database/server.

But still, nodejs or websockets are better tecnologies to deal with real time chats.

Comment: This is a 5 year old question. User already said in 2011 "it's just occurred to me that I didn't put any sleep time in the while loop on the server." And the accepted answer already recommended Node.JS and websockets.